# Visual Studio 2017 only connects 1 project in multi project solution to Git repo

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've got a visual studio solution that contains 3 projects with 3 different Git repositories. While the main project is connected to git and works perfectly well, changes in the other projects are ignored and commit / sync commands are unavailable for those projects.

In the "Solution Explorer" there are icons on the main project showing it's connected to a Git repo but not on the other projects. The main project also has the source control menu item, which the other projects don't have.

I've added all the repos on the "Manage Connections" page. I've also tried deleting the projects and re-adding them by cloning from the manage connections page but those repos are still ignored by visual studio. I have the same problem across multiple machines.

I work across two machines, and the number of hours I've wasted due to a partially synced solution is becoming a massive issue.

Comment: If any of these projects are "library" style projects, submodules might help, but so could using a separate Git UI application. But either way, you need to work with each repository in separate commits and updates and no tool is going to make that seamless.

Comment: @crashmstr I'm already using a separate UI as VS is forcing me to. If JetBrains can make the process virtually seamless in Rider then I'm pretty sure MS can do the same.

Comment: Visual Studio expects you to be in a single Repo. And enforces you to be. If you want to work with a "composed repository", you could setup Git Submodules which tracks the relation between these repos. Or setup NuGet publishing from the dependent projects and break the solution dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as there's no obvious answer to this I've knocked up a couple of `.bat` scripts that others might find useful. These scripts only work if all repos have a common root. Place the scripts and the root and run them.

To add, commit and push everything you can use the following with a parameter as the commit message.

```
echo off

IF NOT %2.==. (
  echo More than one parameter passed. Please ensure your commit message is surrounded with quotes
  GOTO :End
);

IF %1.==. (
  echo No Commit Message. Please pass a commit message as the first parameter.
  GOTO :End
)

set commitmessage=%~1

for /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b .\') do cd /d .\%%f & call git add --all && git commit -m "%commitmessage%" & git push & cd ..

:End
```

To pull everything you can use

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /ad /b .\') do cd /d .\%%f & call git pull & cd ..
```